# How can I define the data type used for a dynamic column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

For normal database columns Rails automatically chooses a matching Ruby data type depending on the column type, i.e. `decimal`/`integer`/`varchar` columns end up being `BigDecimal`/ `Fixnum`/`String` attributes.

But if I query the database using a calculated column

```
Model.select(['models.*', 'calculated_int_column']).other_arel_stuff
```

The attribute `calculated_int_column` always contains a `String` object, even if I use an explicit cast to `integer` in the select statement.

I'd guess this is because Rails uses the schema to look up the column types.

**How can I tell Rails which Ruby type to use for this column?**

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the answer you want, but you could overwrite the getter method to return an integer:

```
class Model
  def calculated_int_column
    @calculated_int_column = 0 if @calculated_int_column.nil?
    @calculated_int_column.to_i
  end
end
```

Comment: I'd rather go with `@calculated_int_column.to_i unless @calculated_int_column.nil?` but besides that I was hoping for a more general solution, since I have many calculated attributes. (Although future caching functionality might reduce them)

Comment: Yeah I wasn't sure if having a nil value returned might break your application, was just putting the first line in just in case.